# How to Open another Form without closing the whole Application c#

Tags: c#

I have Forms (Admin, login, user). There is no error when accessing user form, it is simply opening it without user and pass.

The error I encountered is when I login and Admin form is present, when I click in my toolstripbutton the whole application exits.

This is the method I applied in every toolstripbutton:

```
public void CloseAllActiveForms()
        {
            List<Form> openForms = new List<Form>();

            foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
                openForms.Add(f);

            foreach (Form f in openForms)
            {
                if (f.Name != "FrmAdmin")
                {
                    f.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the code in every toolstipbutton:

```
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseAllActiveForms();
            FrmDashboard objFORM = new FrmDashboard();
            objFORM.MdiParent = this;
            objFORM.TopLevel = false;
            objFORM.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            objFORM.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(objFORM);
            objFORM.Show();
        }
```

This is design sample.

[image]

Every click in toolstripbutton supposed to go in pnlMain, but the problem occurs that after logging in and click one of the toolstripbutton it quits the whole windows application.

I tried to search about these and I found almost the same as my problem but the solution I think is not for my problem because I think it is for two forms only and the main form will be put in program.cs, but i have 2 and I think but not sure that my main form is the login. Please enlighten me.

Thank you

Comment: What does your `Program.Main` method look like?

Comment: Im verry sorry for late reply, is program.main is same to program.cs?

Comment: THIS IS THE METHOD IN MY PROGRAM.MAIN.

(Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FrmLogin());)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line in your `program.cs`

```
Application.Run(new FrmLogin());
```

the form `FrmLogin` is the main form of your application.

When the main form of an application is closed, the application is terminated. I suppose that after Login, you do not close but only hide the login form.

However, your code in `CloseAllActiveForms` will also close the hidden login form.

A quick solution is probably to skip all hidden forms in `CloseAllActiveForms` or explicitly skip `FrmLogin` in `CloseAllActiveForms`.

```
public void CloseAllActiveForms()
{
    List<Form> openForms = new List<Form>();

    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        openForms.Add(f);

    foreach (Form f in openForms)
    {
        if (f.Visible && !(f is FrmAdmin) && !(f is FrmLogin))
        {
            f.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

---

There are alternative cleaner solutions:

1. Show the login form from the main form. See [how to show login form on front & Mainform Behind Login Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716362/how-to-show-login-form-on-front-mainform-behind-login-form)
2. Pass an `ApplicationContext` instead of a Form to Application.Run. This allows you to have more control over when the application is closed. See [Windows Forms: create the main application after login, which form to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629205/windows-forms-create-the-main-application-after-login-which-form-to-run)